# Мульти пакетый репозиторий через php composer

Tags: php, composer

### Что есть

- основной гит репозиторий (project-repository) в котором проект на основе cms
- структура репозитория

  - **composer.json** c зависимостью на cms-framework и один из дополнительных
    пакетов описаных ниже

  ```
  "type": "project",
  "repositories": {
     "ext-repository": {
         "type": "git",
         "url": "https://github.com/vendor/ext-repository"
     }
  },
  {
    "name": "cms/project",
    "require": {
      "cms/framework": "2.0",
      "my/google-auth": "1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "CMS\\": ""
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  - src/
- дополнительный гит репозиторий (ext-repository) с несколькими пакетами которые расширяют возможности вышеуказаной cms
- структура репозитория

  - extensions/

    - google-auth

      - composer.json
      - src/
    - yandex-auth

      - composer.json
      - src/
- установка для разработки с помощью composer install

### Проблема

- Так как ext-repository не содержит composer.json то composer install не подтянет google-auth

### Что нужно

- Использовать только один ext-repository для хранения всех доп. пакетов
- google-auth должен вытягиваться из ext-repository, так как это установка для разработки а не для продакшина

### Что пробывал

- композер метапакеты просто групируют зависимости в один пакет, неподходит так как у меня зависимость на конкретный пакет а не на группу
- composer 2.0 c новой функцией [multiple repositories](https://php.watch/articles/composer-2#repo-filters) оказалась безполезная, так как выборка пакетов происходит по имени пакета а не директории
- git submodules не подходит так как от этот подход использовался раньше и было решено перейти на чистую composer установку
- composer c функцией [replace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace) частично помогает в виде костыля, например в project-composer.json я добавляю 2 зависимости, первый это пакет который содержит все доп. пакеты (super-ext-package) а второй уже конкретный google-auth. В super-ext-package указан replace для google-auth. Таким образом google-auth всегда будет грузиться из super-ext-package и никогда не будет использоваться оригинальный. Этот вариант не подходит потому что всегда после git pull нужно править composer.json добавлением туда super-ext-package

### Замечания

- это упрощенный тестовый пример в жизни все сложней, поэтому такие странные требования, я бы не хотел получить ответ "храни все пакеты в отдельных репозиториях"
- сейчас установка происходит слиянием папки extensions внутрь основного проекта, что является весьма неудобным для CI и разработки.
- в этом примере обсуждает только установка для разработки, для продакшина все значительно проще, в пакагист забрасываются уже конкретные пакеты с конкретными зависимостями, но паковать все и постоянно для целей разработки нельзя

Comment: А  в чем принципиальное отличие 1 репозитория от нескольких  с тем урл но разными названиями пакетов url/extensions/my-name, url/extensions/my-name2 ?

Comment: @rodigy я не понял как вы предлагаете это сделать. Урл всегда имеет структуру https://github.com/git-vendor/repository и присуствует в секции repositories, а имена пакетов это всегда packagist-vendor/package. Если же говорить про отличие одного репозитория от нескольких то ответ это очень неудобно содержать 100 репозиториев в гите + доп. описывать в composer.json, разработчику неудобно делать кучу пул реквестов в разные репозитории

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```json
{
  "type": "project",
  "repositories": [
    {
       "type": "vsc",
       "url": "https://github.com/vendor/ext-repository",
       "package-path": "extensions/my/google-auth/"
    },
    {
       "type": "vsc",
       "url": "https://github.com/vendor/ext-repository",
       "package-path": "extensions/my/yandex-auth/"
    }
  ],
  "name": "cms/project",
  "require": {
    "cms/framework": "2.0",
    "my/google-auth": "1.0",
    "my/yandex-auth": "1.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "CMS\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```